# Failed to load resource for Gboard stickers on Android

Tags: java, android, xiaomi, miui

I created an Android app with Gboard stickers that works on some devices while on others it does not.

On my Honor 10 device it works as expected while on my Xiaomi Mi 9 it prints this error to logcat when I try to insert the sticker anywhere:

```
04-26 20:52:57.650  2027 11006 W Glide   : Load failed for android.resource://cz.chrastecky.chstickers/drawable/st002 with size [-2147483648x-2147483648]
04-26 20:52:57.650  2027 11006 W Glide   : class axi: Failed to load resource
04-26 20:52:57.651  2027  2027 W Glide   : Load failed for null with size [0x0]
04-26 20:52:57.651  2027  2027 W Glide   : class axi: Received null model
04-26 20:52:57.653  2027  9448 W Image   : Caught Error: likely due to not having both file formats
04-26 20:52:57.653  2027  9448 W Image   : class axi: Failed to load resource
04-26 20:52:57.653  2027  9449 W Image   : Caught Error: likely due to not having both file formats
04-26 20:52:57.653  2027  9449 W Image   : class axi: Received null model
04-26 20:52:57.654  2027  2027 E ImageInsertTask: Failed to extract local cache file for android.resource://cz.chrastecky.chstickers/drawable/st002
```

I can't find anything on Google about this type of error, please point me in the right direction.

Update as requested in comments:

**Honor 10 (working)**

- Android version: `9`
- Gboard version: `8.1.7.241875604-release-arm64-v8a`
- Firebase App Indexing info:

  - `Sticker: 79`
  - `StickerPack: 1`

**Xiaomi Mi 9 (not working)**

- Android version: `9 PKQ1.181121.001`
- Gboard version: `8.1.7.241875604-release-arm64-v8a` (same as Honor 10)
- Firebase App Indexing info (same as Honor 10):

  - `Sticker: 79`
  - `StickerPack: 1`

According to a report from one user it also doesn't work on `One UI` system from Samsung.

Comment: What is the respective Android version of these 2 devices? What is the Gboard version?

Comment: Assuming you use firebase, What are the indexable details for your app on these 2 devices (Settings > Google > Firebase App Indexing)?

Comment: @rds I updated it with more info.